# Is TLSv1.3 supported in OpenJDK 11 under Ubuntu?

Tags: java, ubuntu, ssl, transport-security

On Ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install openjdk-11-source
```

results in a `ProtocolVersion.java` that does not know about TLSv1.3 .
Is there any way to correct that (without restrictive licencing)?

Comment: so installing https://jdk.java.net/11/ might work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that for some reason, Ubuntu actually ships Java 10 under openjdk-11-* packages.

Answer (score 2):

### Update

Since [April 23rd 2019](http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/changelogs/pool/main/o/openjdk-lts/openjdk-lts_11.0.3+7-1ubuntu2~18.04.1/changelog), Ubuntu (18.04 LTS and more recent editions) ships with a JRE/JDK version [*11.0.3*](https://packages.ubuntu.com/de/bionic/openjdk-11-jdk). For this reason, the original answer by *alamar* is outdated.

For reasons of curiosity, I wrote a little TLS v1.3 check tool that programmatically checks the TLS v1.3 support of a target *runtime* environment. This way, one can quickly spot what's going on:

```
public class TLS13Checker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SSLContext context = null;
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("PKIX");
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();
            context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.3");
            context.init(null, trustAllCerts, new SecureRandom());

            SSLParameters params = context.getSupportedSSLParameters();
            String[] protocols = params.getProtocols();
            System.out.println("Java version : " + System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));
            boolean supportsTLSv13 = false;
            for (String protocol : protocols) {
                if ("TLSv1.3".equals(protocol)) {
                    supportsTLSv13 = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(supportsTLSv13) {
                System.out.println("JRE supports TLS v1.3!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("JRE does NOT support TLS v1.3!");
            }
            String[] suites = params.getCipherSuites();
            System.out.println("A total of " + suites.length + " TLS cipher suites is supported.");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException | KeyStoreException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(42);
        }

    }
}
```

You can simply compile and run it, and the output will be similar to what I got with a recent *OpenJDK* environment (under MacOS):

```
Java version : 11.0.3+7
JRE supports TLS v1.3!
A total of 45 TLS cipher suites is supported.
```

In addition, this list gives an overview over all regular [JSSE Cipher Suite Names](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/security/standard-names.html#jsse-cipher-suite-names). It might be helpful for reference or other (implementation) purposes.

Hope it helps.